# Execute python script through Java

Tags: python, java, csv

I'm trying to run a very simple python script that clears and writes to a CSV file, from inside of java but I'm having a lot of trouble doing it.

The scripts don't require any input and the output is all written into a CSV file so ***all I need to do is get the python scripts to run through my java code.***

Below is a bit of code that I've seen all over the internet but doesn't seem to be working for me. It seems like for both of the scripts, using this command does nothing to the csv. No errors are thrown and the java program simply exits presumably without executing the python scripts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python Refresh.py");
    }
```

here are the scripts I'm trying to run.

Script1:

```
file = open("products.csv","r+")
file.truncate(0)
file.close()
```

Script2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import time

filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename, "a")


#connects to the page and reads and saves raw HTML
for i in (0,25,50,75):
    my_url = 'https://www.adorama.com/l/Computers/Computer-Components/Video-and-Graphics-Cards?startAt='+ str(i) +'&sel=Expansion-Ports_HDMI'
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    client = Request(my_url,headers=hdr)
    page = urlopen(client).read()

    #parsing the HTML
    page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")
    #print (page_soup.h1)

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item"})
    #print (len(containers))
    containers.pop()
    for container in containers:
        
        title_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"item-details"})
        title = title_container[0].h2.a.text.strip()

        status_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"item-actions"})
        status = status_container[0].form.button.text.strip()

        if (status == "Temporarily not available"):
            status = "Out of stock"
        else:
            status = "In stock"
        
        price = container.find("div","prices").input["value"]

        link = container.a["href"]

        f.write(title.replace(",", "|") + "," + price.replace(",", "") + "," + status + "," + link + "\n")

        time.sleep(0.01)
f.close()
```

The java file, Python script, and the csv file are all in the same folder.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite these python scripts in Java?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Exceptions? Have you tried giving the full path for the python executable and for the script to see if that's the problem?

Comment: No errors no exceptions. The program just runs and exits. I've also tried giving the full path of the python executable but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: A) you really want to have the full path to the python binary in that command B) start with a simple python script that just prints something to stdout C) then use the Java process interfaces to **READ** what that script wrote, and so on. Start small. And yes, why mix two languages for this?

Comment: Thanks, will try this. As for the mix of languages, I had a terrible experience with webscraping in Java and found it way simpler in python and was much more successful. So I'd like to just change the webscraping portion of my java project to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by constantly reading the "print" and error outputs of the Python file. Whilst I still don't completely understand how this fixed the issue, my best guess is that with this, the Java code keeps the python script "running" until the script itself is finished doing its thing, instead of just opening the script and instantly moving on.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String[] callAndArgs = {"python3", "YourScript.py"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs);
        
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        
        String s;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(s);
        }

        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

}
```

Another Notable Detail is that this code only seems to work when Compiled and run through the Terminal/Geany. If I run the same thing with IntelliJ **it does not work**. Once again, I'm not sure why this is but I'm suspecting that IntelliJ compiles and runs in a VM of some sorts.

Comment: It may not be working because the two streams must be consumed at same time, not one after the other. See my answer below - the `.redirectErrorStream(true)` part means that there is no stream deadlock.

Comment: Would that be a reason for it to work in Geany but not in Intellij??? That doesn't make sense to me. I'll still implement the change your recommended. Thanks :)

Comment: Results may be different if JVM is different, but also check error messages and result codes

Answer (score 2):

Use the newer ProcessBuilder class:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","Refresh.py");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. The java program simply runs and exits without any edits being made to the CSV file. No errors thrown either.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking for errors from the python script. You can achieve this simply by merging STDERR to STDOUT and reporting the content of STDOUT to console:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("python", "Refresh.py")
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start();
p.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

This should print out the error message from python and give you error code back. You may have problems with path to files, so you might need to adjust your arguments to explicit pathnames to "python" and/or "Refresh.py".

Comment: Going of the same idea, I created input buffers and kept reading the python output which now seems to actually wait to for the python script to finish running before moving along. Thanks!